# R - Gamma distribution - Linear Mixed-Effects Model - lmer/glmer errors

Tags: r, glm, lme4, gamma-distribution

First time asking here so please let me know if anything else is needed to be able to help!

I have analysed my data using `lmer()` which worked well. I have since realised that a Gamma distribution is more fitting than the Gaussian I am currently using.  To be able to use this I believe I have to use the GLMER instead.

I have been trying to run it but am coming across an error I don't understand, and I can't find the answer to googling about.  My code currently looks like this;

`glmer(primordial.cm ~ sr * bw + (1|litter) + sw + sa, data = counts, na.action = na.exclude, family=Gamma)`

and the error I am getting is;

```
Error in pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tol = tolPwrss, GQmat = GQmat, compDev = compDev,  : 
  PIRLS loop resulted in NaN value
```

I guess my question is twofold -
Is there a way to still use `lmer` but with a Gamma distribution?
What is the error message telling me/how do I fix it?

Many thanks for any help!

Edit;
Following comment this is the `df` output using the first 20 rows

```
dput(head(counts, 20))
structure(list(tag = structure(c(1L, 3L, 7L, 32L, 24L, 2L, 4L, 
8L, 9L, 13L, 33L, 37L, 36L, 38L, 39L, 27L, 28L, 10L, 11L, 12L
), .Label = c("1137", "1140", "1257", "1258", "16", "17", "1882", 
"1883", "1912", "1920", "1921", "1923", "1928", "210", "212", 
"22", "222", "24", "250", "312", "3655", "391", "403", "471", 
"478", "479", "482", "483", "484", "490", "502", "5620", "5650", 
"5688", "6627", "Y558", "Y649", "Y862", "Y869"), class = "factor"), 
    bw = c(1.47, 1.63, 2.4, 1.51, 1.43, 1.39, 1.67, 
    2.18, 1.02, 1.9, 1.32, 1.1, 1.48, 1.25, 1.45, 1.46, 1.43, 
    1.81, 1.36, 1.37), sw = c(96.2, 96.1, 106.6, 
    114.64, 106.1333, 97.4, 102.6, 109, 114.2, 119.32, 109.8714, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 108.27, 109.5333, 117.45, 116.76, 107.66), 
    litter = c("3", "5", "11", "9", "6", "3", "5", "11", "1", 
    "1", "9", "21", "21", "20", "20", "10", "10", "7", "12", 
    "12"), sa = c(155, 154, 160, 172, 180, 155, 154, 
    160, 167, 167, 179, 174, 174, 174, 174, 174, 181, 168, 168, 
    175), sex.ratio... = c(70L, 75L, 75L, 53L, 47L, 70L, 75L, 
    75L, 27L, 27L, 53L, 71L, 71L, 50L, 50L, 47L, 47L, 46L, 50L, 
    50L), sr = c(0.7, 0.75, 0.75, 0.53, 0.47, 0.7, 0.75, 
    0.75, 0.27, 0.27, 0.53, 0.71, 0.71, 0.5, 0.5, 0.47, 0.47, 
    0.46, 0.5, 0.5), bias = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Male-biased", 
    "Non-biased", "Female-biased"), class = "factor"), primordial.cm = c(114.6903044, 
    47.31075931, 117.9993577, 57.00768991, 21.14809511, 100.2912585, 
    48.62879289, 163.7782553, 420.2023737, 22.90648124, 155.5015055, 
    134.0178424, 37.92752873, 20.88138829, 50.34685719, 105.6690685, 
    113.7977974, 77.58597154, 53.58654997, 73.89749036), ), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please share the data with ```dput()```? If it has many rows then you can use ```dput(head(df, 20))``` which will give the first 20 rows.

Comment: I have edited the question to include it there, too long for the comments, is that what's needed?

Comment: It should always be added to the question. And yes, it is what is needed. It will be complete if you can add the coding blocks for the sample data frame too.

Comment: I'll remember that for the future. I believe Nad Pat helped me by editing that in.

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions here? :

https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/573

Comment: We probably need the full data set to be able to resolve this ... can you post it somewhere and include the link?

Comment: Are you willing to consider a log link rather than an inverse link? Generally much more stable ...

Answer (score 2):

I was receiving the same error, which was resolved after following Ben Bolker's advice and switching to a log link